# Loading fail2ban filters from subdirectory

Tags: fail2ban

Is it possible for fail2ban to load filters from a folder within `/etc/fail2ban/filters`? For instance, if I set up a file at `/etc/fail2ban/filters/custom/log4j.conf`, could I load that filter in my `jail.local` and how would the syntax differ? I've done some research online and not found anything relevant to that in the documentation.

The reason I'm asking is we have a number of bespoke filters for common attacks (eg one for Wordpress login attempts, one for the XMLRPC attack, one for Log4j etc) and it would be useful to keep them in sync by having a directory of custom filters within a Git repository that can be cloned and and kept up to date via regular pulls from the repository.

We could possibly achieve this by using provisioning tools like Ansible to apply changes in fail2ban configuration to multiple servers, and indeed I've used Ansible for exactly this use case in the past, but that was in a case where I was also using Ansible for provisioning the servers in the first place, and it's probably not worth doing it just for keeping fail2ban filters in sync if there's a simpler alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd place your filters in `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/`.
In this case you'd use it in the jail like:

```ini
[jail]
filter = name-of-filter
```

This will use `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/name-of-filter.conf`.
And you don't need to specify that if your filter is called with the same name as the jail (this is default).

Also you can use the jail without the filter. Simply set `filter =` and add your `datepattern`, `prefregex` and `failregex` directly in jail.

More in [man jail.conf.5](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/fail2ban/jail.conf.5.en.html#JAIL_CONFIGURATION_FILE(S)_(jail.conf)).

Comment: I'm aware of that - I've been using fail2ban successfully for half a decade. What I'm trying to do is load the filters from a directory so that I can use version control to keep them in sync on multiple servers because a provisioning tool like Ansible would be overkill.

Comment: You can use them in any directory (just ensure the path of include, like comon, etc are relative). Another variant is a hard- or a sym-link, so you can use VCS/SCM on a linked path.